# Register add-ins, project templates and item templates for Visual Studio 11

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3

I've been using Wix 3.5 with WixVSExtension to install project item templates for Visual Studio 2010, Visual C# 2010 Express and Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. I'd like now to add support for Visual Studio 11 Beta.

I added registry search and custom actions to find the VS11 installation folders but, when specifying directory and components structure, I'm getting compilation errors like this one:

error LGHT0204: ICE30: The target file 'ewa5nwrn.zip|BasicApplication.zip' is installed in '[TARGETDIR]\CSharp\' by two different components on an LFN system: 'VS2010CSharpProjectTemplates' and 'VS11CSharpProjectTemplates'. This breaks component reference counting.

I have this directory structure:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="VS2010_PROJECTTEMPLATES_DIR">
    <Directory Id="VS2010_PROJECTTEMPLATES_CSHARP_DIR" Name="CSharp">
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="VS11_PROJECTTEMPLATES_DIR">
    <Directory Id="VS11_PROJECTTEMPLATES_CSHARP_DIR" Name="CSharp">
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Notice that I have VS2010_PROJECTTEMPLATES_DIR and VS11_PROJECTTEMPLATES_DIR inside TARGETDIR. The error message shows that they are ignored.

The components are defined as follow:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="VS2010_PROJECTTEMPLATES_CSHARP_DIR">
  <Component Id="VS2010CSharpProjectTemplates" Guid="{0976A222-8243-40F2-81AB-84D8F1771840}" Transitive="yes">
    <File Id="VS2010BasicApplication" Source="BasicApplication.zip" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>

<DirectoryRef Id="VS11_PROJECTTEMPLATES_CSHARP_DIR">
  <Component Id="VS11CSharpProjectTemplates" Guid="{A70428F1-AE26-4B07-9F58-D67587B44657}" Transitive="yes">
    <File Id="VS11BasicApplication" Source="BasicApplication.zip" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Is it possible to install the same file into two different directories specified by properties?

Thanks in advance,
aalmada

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any source code to share but I can tell you in general how I've done this in the past.

We decided to "install" the zip files to our main application directory in a `Integration` folder so that the files would always be available even if VS2008 and/or VS2010 had not been installed at the time of installation.  I then used a bunch of built-in properties that exist in the Util extension and a couple custom RegLocator searches  to define a bunch of properties related to the location of devenv.exe and ItemTemplate, ProjectTemplates and other directories that we needed in .NET.    I then used those properties in CopyFile elements so that MSI would duplicate those files in the `Integration` folder to the actual VS directories as needed and approriate.   Finally I used the WiX QuietExec custom action to call Devenv /setup to register the content with VS.  I also used the ProgressText element ( ActionText table ) to make the UI look good while this was all happening as VS devenv can take awhile.

Comment: I think that using `CopyFile` is not appropriate, as it will result in the copied files never being uninstalled. I guess you could handle that by also using the `RemoveFile` element, but it would be better to just use the normal component installation logic which  should take care of all this automatically.

Comment: Wix 3.5 supports same file installation in multiple directories. You just need to set different IDs for each <file> reference. My problems was sightly different..

Comment: Wim- That's not true.  We never had problems with uninstall and we supported targeting 2005, 2008 and 2010.  The nice thing about the duplicate files was if the property was never set to a value it would quietly not do anything.  This solution replaced a VDPROJ instlaller that used insane InstallUtil custom actions and it passed all validation tests and behaved wonderfully.  It was very elegant.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the wix documentation of the [Directory](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_directory.htm) element: when you omit the `Name` attribute you are creating **an alias for the parent `Directory` element**.

This is done by recording "." as the directory name in the installer database, as explained in the windows installer documentation for the [Directory table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In your case, I believe you attempt to change this "." value into a real directory name by setting the `VS2010_PROJECTTEMPLATES_DIR` and `VS11_PROJECTTEMPLATES_DIR` properties (because [directories are properties](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2006/10/17/deciphering-the-msi-directory-table-part-7-directories-are-properties.aspx)) during the installation.

That's fine, but the problem here is that the `light` linker doesn't know what values you will set these properties to during the installation. It only has the `Name` attribute value to work with. And at link time, it looks like you are installing the same file twice to the same directory.

**To fix this, add `Name` attributes with different placeholder values to the VS2010_PROJECTTEMPLATES_DIR and VS11_PROJECTTEMPLATES_DIR directory elements.**

Comment: Adding a Name property to VS2010_PROJECTTEMPLATES_DIR and VS11_PROJECTTEMPLATES_DIR didn't work but adding base directories with Name properties set did work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up adding two base directories, under TARGETDIR, with the Name properties set:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="VS2010" Name="VS2010">
    <Directory Id="VS2010_PROJECTTEMPLATES_DIR">
      <Directory Id="VS2010_PROJECTTEMPLATES_CSHARP_DIR" Name="CSharp">
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="VS11" Name="VS11">
    <Directory Id="VS11_PROJECTTEMPLATES_DIR">
      <Directory Id="VS11_PROJECTTEMPLATES_CSHARP_DIR" Name="CSharp">
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Here is the code for the properties (based on the WixVSExtension code):

```
<Property Id="VS11DEVENV" Secure="yes">
  <RegistrySearch Id="VS11DevEnvSearch" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Setup\VS" Name="EnvironmentPath" Type="raw"/>
</Property>

<Property Id="VS11_ROOT_FOLDER" Secure="yes">
  <RegistrySearch Id="SearchForVS11RootPath" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" Name="11.0" Type="raw"/>
</Property>

<Property Id="VS11_PROJECTTEMPLATES_DIR" Secure="yes">
  <RegistrySearch Id="VS11DevEnvForProjectTemplatesSearch" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Setup\VS" Name="EnvironmentDirectory" Type="raw">
    <DirectorySearch Id="VS11ProjectTemplatesPathSearch" Path="ProjectTemplates" Depth="1" />
  </RegistrySearch>
</Property>

<Property Id="VS11_ITEMTEMPLATES_DIR" Secure="yes">
  <RegistrySearch Id="VS11DevEnvForItemTemplatesSearch" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Setup\VS" Name="EnvironmentDirectory" Type="raw">
    <DirectorySearch Id="VS11ItemTemplatesPathSearch" Path="ItemTemplates" Depth="1" />
  </RegistrySearch>
</Property>

<CustomAction Id="VS11InstallVSTemplates" Property="VS11DEVENV" ExeCommand="/InstallVSTemplates" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no" />
```

I then found out that the VS2010 templates don't expand correctly under VS11 but that's a different question now... :-/

Comment: WiX 3.6 RC0 was just announced today.  That's probably were you'll find support for VS11* properties.

Comment: I upgraded to WiX 3.6 RC0 and now I'm using new WixVSExtension properties and actions for Visual Studio 11. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Can you share with us how did you manage to install it under 2012 Express Desktop edition?